# AWS S3 presigned url results in SignatureDoesNotMatch error due to blank space android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a String font name(Joyful Juliana)in my S3 which has a blank space in between its name as seen. Its key is shown as **Joyful Juliana** and the url has Joyful+Juliana encoding format.

On the app side, I tried handling it with URLEncoding but I get SignatureDoesNotMatch error.

I tried with String.replace() and String.replaceAll() functions, but still get the same error.

This is how I generate the presigned URL:

```
public String generatePresignedURL(String key) {
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(defaultBucketName, key);
    String url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toString();
    return url;
}
```

The key that I have passed is this

```
String.format("files/fonts/%s", fontItem.getName())
```

Looks like AWS handles the encoding of url in its own way as shown in **S3HttpUtils** Class.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the guidelines by S3 for object key names: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

The following character sets are generally safe for use in key names:

Alphanumeric characters [0-9a-zA-Z]

Special characters !, -, _, ., *, ', (, and )

It is up to the SDKs to implement handling for special characters that are not safe according to S3. The AWS Android SDK - 2.3.x and earlier versions used to handle this correctly. There was a regression introduced in 2.4.0 which encodes the non-safe characters and hence you get the error.

The suggestion would be to use the safe characters only in your key names if you are using the latest version.